# How to find the logs which have generated

Tags: azure, azure-functions

What are the ways to find a log that we have generated using azure function or trigger in azure portal

Thanks in Advance, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the approach is using Kusto query, you can find a log which was generated by azure function in portal by following below steps:

- Go to Azure Portal=> then Select your function app=> select logs from left side pane=> Then you write your kusto query

***Example query:***

```
traces
| where message contains "starting"
```

***Output:***

[image]